# Apache + PHP-FPM Pool Options - resources consumed and traffic estimated

Tags: php, linux, apache, cpanel, whm

For e dedicated server with WHM/cPanel configured with Apache + PHP-FPM the default **Pool Options** per domain are:

```
Max Children = 5
Process Idle Timeout = 10
Max Requests = 20
```

**The questions are:**

1. How many resources are involved when it reaches the limit with default Pool Options configuration?(memory and CPU).
2. How many traffic can deal the default Pool Options configuration?(unique visitors / connections).
3. Which are the settings for Pool Options for 10000 vistors/day?
4. There is online a simulator/computer who can covert/calculate Pool Options into visitors?

Thanks in advance!